# Extract data from RapidAPI script

Tags: javascript, json

I need help with my JavaScript script. I need to use a RapidAPI API (https://rapidapi.com/Gramzivi/api/covid-19-data).

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/name");

req.query({
    "date": "2020-04-07",
    "name": "France"
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-key": "9dbec807afmshfc71e9c91b72096p1a5798jsn0dea120c3f1a",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
    "useQueryString": true
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

I would like to be able to extract the data every day, and reuse it in the rest of the script. I have used the script code but it returns 'undefined'. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never expose your API key to the public, so I would strongly suggest getting a new key. I will re-use it because it's already been exposed and I want to show you how it should work.

Your code looks correct, and if I run it on my machine then I get the correct data back. I'm not familiar with Unirest, but the one step you may be missing is to convert the response body to JSON instead of a ReadableStream object. Try running this in your console:

```js
fetch("https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/name?date=2020-04-07&name=France", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "9dbec807afmshfc71e9c91b72096p1a5798jsn0dea120c3f1a",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json() )
.then(data => {
    console.log("Total confirmed in province of France: " + data[0].provinces.filter(p => p.province === "France")[0].confirmed);
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thx for your help. Now i have i have another problem. I want to use the parameter confirmed of the province France. But when i call it :

.then(data => {console.log(data.province.confirmed)})

i was an undefined error. How to fix it pls ?

Comment: You will need to review how to access data in a javascript object. This is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects -

Since `"provinces"` is an array, you'll need to filter the array to get France. You can't access it directly. Try `data[0].provinces.filter(p => p.province === "France")[0].confirmed`. I'm updating my answer with that now.